# C++ - Vector causing errors

Tags: c++, vector

the below class spits out around 20 errors, but if I comment out the vector bullets it seems to be all fine.  Am I missing some obvious error?

```
#include <vector>
#include "SDL.h"
#include "Bullet.h"

#ifndef GAMEDATA_H
#define GAMEDATA_H

class GameData
{
public:
    GameData();
    ~GameData();
    GameData(const GameData& data);
    GameData& operator=(const GameData* rhs);

    vector<Bullet> bullets;

    SDL_Surface* shipimage;
    SDL_Surface* bulletimage;
};

#endif
```

Comment: The responses so far are probably correct, but you need to be specific and include the exact error messages you are getting. It makes a difference most times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vector` is inside namespace `std`. Modify you `bullets` declaration to:

```
std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `vector` is declared in `namespace std`. Change the type to `std::vector` and all will be fine.

In your source files, if you use `std` members excessively you might find it useful to declare:

```
using namespace std;
```

Before any other code lines. This will allow you to access the `std` member without the `std::` qualifier. This is exactly why you do not see `std::` infront of most examples - they declare this directive.

Comment: Worth noting that `using namespace std;` is generally bad way to solve this, as it will pull much more symbols than `vector`, `string` etc into global namespace.

Comment: I was about to say that exact thing. It's good to tell him why examples usually use it, but not to advise him to use the "using namespace" directive.

Comment: I think that `using namespace` is fine, as long as its scope is restricted. I sometimes use it inside the function scope, where it is just another implementation detail that I can change at any time. I also think that `using namespace` in (small) source files is fine, because changing it in case of conflicts is still cheap. The real culprit is `using namespace` in a header file, because this will pollute the global namespace in any file that is including that header.